# Ejecutar .jar en MacOS

Tags: java, macos

tengo una duda y es que no puedo hacer correr archivos .jar en mi mac. El archivo es xlogo.jar se lo descarga desde la pagina oficial: http://xlogo.tuxfamily.org/sp/descargas.html es para enseñar a niños lo básico de programación. 
En teoria, debería ejecutarse apenas haciendo doble click sobre el archivo; pero por alguna razón lo asocia a un descompresor. Ya he instalado java, jre, jdk. Todo. También he intentado escribiendo en la terminal: *java -jar* **xlogo.jar** y me aparece lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, porque estoy desconcertado. Se que no es el archivo porque corre en otra macbook, no  se cual es el problema especificamente. Gracias.

Comment: Sucede porque el que empaquetó el jar olvidó incluir la dependencia jogl, que es una librería para uso de OpenGL en Java. Además, parece ser que hay distintas versiones de jogl de acuerdo al SO. Mejor es que pidas el fuente al autor. Así mismo, mira si pide ciertos requisitos que debed cumplir.

Comment: Funciona en otra mac, es decir, en la iMac no asocia el .jar a java; lo asocia a un descompresor de archivos. Intente hace click derecho y abrir con otros y buscar java, pero en las aplicaciones no aparece.

Comment: Para ejecutar el .jar debes tener instalada la Java Virtual Machine (JVM) en tu Mac. Es importante tener siempre la última versión. Se suele instalar / actualizar con el paquete **completo** de Java disponible en la página de descargas.

Comment: Ya lo instale. No se cual es el problema. Simplemente no asocia los archivos. En la terminal uso el comando: java -version y sale "version 1.8.0_131" la ultima a la fecha. Sinceramente no entiendo que es lo que pasa, de momento estoy trabajando con una maquina virtual en Windows, porque me canse de buscar una solucion...

Comment: ¿`javax.media.opengl` es parte de la librería jogl verdad?

Comment: Tal vez te interese esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818437/6999690

Answer (score 2):

> #### Nota de edición
>
> Dado que @RuslanLopez no entendió la intención de la respuesta, la
>   edito para que quede más claro, gracias a la sugerencia de @Elenasys.

### Reproducción del problema para encontrar una respuesta

A fin de encontrar una **respuesta**, he reproducido el problema en un entorno con `Mac OSx Sierra`.

El resultado es que me sale el mismo error que a ti:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/media/opengl/GLException    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)  at
>   javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$1.run(Pipeline.java:162)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.media.j3d.Pipeline.createPipeline(Pipeline.java:157)    at
>   javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:965)
>     at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.(VirtualUniverse.java:299)
>     at xlogo.Logo.main(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 8 more
>   Closing XLogo. Cleaning tmp file

Mirando en la consola, se ve que **no funciona debido a un problema que tiene que ver con la seguridad**:

```
assessment denied for xlogo.jar
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.security.assessment.outcome2
com.apple.message.signature2: bundle:UNBUNDLED
com.apple.message.signature3: xlogo.jar
com.apple.message.signature5: UNKNOWN
com.apple.message.signature4: 3
com.apple.message.signature: denied:no usable signature
SenderMachUUID: 295213F8-F12F-3676-9CC8-EC3AD4E8AC4B
```

---

### Probando con Web Start (según sugerencia del autor)

También traté de ejecutarlo usando `Java Web Start`, [como ellos explican aquí](https://xlogo.tuxfamily.org/en/download-en.html):

> Java Web Start
>
> Now, you can start XLogo directly from a web page using 'Java Web
>   Start' (you still need a JRE installed). Just click the following
>   link:
>
> Start XLogo on line.

Otra vez un error debido a la seguridad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El enlace que dice Más información, [es este](https://java.com/es/download/help/jcp_security.xml).

---

### Posible obsolescencia y propuesta de solución

En la página dicen que la última versión de `Mac OS` probada es: **Mac OS X (Tiger Leopard)**, la cual data ya de algunos añitos.

Por otro lado, [**ellos ofrecen el código fuente en este enlace**](https://svn.tuxfamily.org/viewvc.cgi/xlogo_xlogosvn/), una posible solución sería descargarlo y compilarlo, y si te da error de compilación podrías agregar las clases que falten de la librería `javax/media/opengl/`, pues es lo que indica el mensaje de error o bien contactar directamente con quienes han creado o mantienen el proyecto.

Si el proyecto ya no es mantenido y no logras adaptarlo a nuevas versiones del sistema operativo, considera probarlo con una versión anterior de Java. O, en último término, buscar otra alternativa que funcione.

En cualquier caso, hay que tener cuidado y usar programas que sean de fuentes fiables.

Comment: Hola, @A.Cedano veo que al final de tu respuesta ofreces una solución solo que al inicio pareciera que comentas que te sucede el mismo problema. ¿Sería bueno redactarla no crees :-)?

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, creo que ahora sí se entiende que es una respuesta, no un planteamiento de que *a mi me pasa lo mismo*. Yo reproduje el problema (instalé el código) para probar, que no es lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema estimado es que el archivo .jar que tienes tu al empaquetarlo no seleccionaron la casilla en la cual se añaden las librerías necesarias para la correcta ejecución del programa.

En la traza del error lo dice falta la Clase:

`javax/media/opengl/GLException`

Comment: Eso no es una respuesta, es un comentario